# Problem with Cognitive Services Speaker Recognition

Tags: c#, azure, helper, voice, azure-cognitive-services

I'm new to ms Azure, but I got the following task, using Azure Cognitive Services Speaker Recognition to confirm that the speaker matches a known or registered voice. There is an article on the microsoft site with an example of how to work with a speech service, but when I run the example it stops on the SpeakerVerify function and cannot process the similarity score result (result = await speakerRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync (model)). Everything is synchronized with Azure. Please help me figure out what the problem is. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace YMM7
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static async Task VerificationEnroll(SpeechConfig config, Dictionary<string, string> profileMapping)
        {
            using (var client = new VoiceProfileClient(config))
            using (var profile = await client.CreateProfileAsync(VoiceProfileType.TextIndependentVerification, "en-us"))
            {
                using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Enrolling profile id {profile.Id}.");
                    // give the profile a human-readable display name
                    profileMapping.Add(profile.Id, "Your Name");

                    VoiceProfileEnrollmentResult result = null;
                    while (result is null || result.RemainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength > TimeSpan.Zero)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Continue speaking to add to the profile enrollment sample.");
                        result = await client.EnrollProfileAsync(profile, audioInput);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Remaining enrollment audio time needed: {result.RemainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength}");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }

                    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.EnrolledVoiceProfile)
                    {
                        
                        await SpeakerVerify(config, profile, profileMapping);
                    }
                    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var cancellation = VoiceProfileEnrollmentCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED {profile.Id}: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode} ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static async Task SpeakerVerify(SpeechConfig config, VoiceProfile profile, Dictionary<string, string> profileMapping)
        {
            var speakerRecognizer = new SpeakerRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput());
            var model = SpeakerVerificationModel.FromProfile(profile);
            

            Console.WriteLine("Speak the passphrase to verify: \"My voice is my passport, verify me.\"");
           
            var result = await speakerRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync(model);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Verified voice profile for speaker {profileMapping[result.ProfileId]}, score is {result.Score}");
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // replace with your own subscription key 
            string subscriptionKey = "1234567890";
            string region = "westus";
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region); 


            var profileMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            await VerificationEnroll(config, profileMapping);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: please add some more detail like what all things you have tried and what exact error you are getting in the following code.

Comment: The purpose of the program is to define a user using Microsoft Azure services. When executing the program, an error occurs when calling the function for determining the similarity score.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't reproduce your error.

I test the code in official document, which works well.
[image]
And I also modify with your code, which stuck on this part:
[image]

I found that the only different is that we use `result.RemainingEnrollmentsCount`, but you use `result.RemainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength`.

Try to use the code in official doc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace SpeakerRecog
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static async Task VerificationEnroll(SpeechConfig config, Dictionary<string, string> profileMapping)
        {
            using (var client = new VoiceProfileClient(config))
            using (var profile = await client.CreateProfileAsync(VoiceProfileType.TextDependentVerification, "en-us"))
            {
                using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput())
                //using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("myVoiceIsMyPassportVerifyMe01.wav"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Enrolling profile id {profile.Id}.");
                    // give the profile a human-readable display name
                    profileMapping.Add(profile.Id, "Doris");

                    VoiceProfileEnrollmentResult result = null;

                    while (result is null || result.RemainingEnrollmentsCount > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Speak the passphrase, \"My voice is my passport, verify me.\"");
                        result = await client.EnrollProfileAsync(profile, audioInput);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Remaining enrollments needed: {result.RemainingEnrollmentsCount}");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }

                    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.EnrolledVoiceProfile)
                    {
                        await SpeakerVerify(config, profile, profileMapping);
                    }
                    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var cancellation = VoiceProfileEnrollmentCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED {profile.Id}: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode} ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task SpeakerVerify(SpeechConfig config, VoiceProfile profile, Dictionary<string, string> profileMapping)
        {
            var speakerRecognizer = new SpeakerRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput());
            //var speakerRecognizer = new SpeakerRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("d:/MyRepository/file/myVoiceIsMyPassportVerifyMe02.wav"));
            var model = SpeakerVerificationModel.FromProfile(profile);

            Console.WriteLine("Speak the passphrase to verify: \"My voice is my passport, please verify me.\"");
            var result = await speakerRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync(model);
            Console.WriteLine($"Verified voice profile for speaker {profileMapping[result.ProfileId]}, score is {result.Score}");
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // replace with your own subscription key 
            string subscriptionKey = "subscriptionKey";
            string region = "westus";
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);

            // persist profileMapping if you want to store a record of who the profile is
            var profileMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            await VerificationEnroll(config, profileMapping);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your code unchanged and got the following error : This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    SpeakerRecog.Program.SpeakerVerify(Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.VoiceProfile, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>) in Program.cs
    [External Code]
    SpeakerRecog.Program.VerificationEnroll(Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>) in Program.cs
    [External Code]
    SpeakerRecog.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs

Comment: @Lubow Use your namespace `YMM7`, not `SpeakerRecog`.

Comment: @JasonPan using YMM7 namespace didn't help